# Short forms for pounds and ounces?

Tags: measuring-units

I have been using ' for pounds and " for ounces for quite a while now,but it was pointed out to me today that my pet cat weighs 6 feet 9 inches.(l wrote 6'9" to a vet). Are these acceptable abbreviations/short forms?
And are those the descriptive words I want? Id est, is " a short form?Abbreviation? What would you call the use of punctuation as a representative mark for a measurement?

Comment: (Perhaps they're Canadianisms,eh? Like tuque and toboggan? ^·_~^ )

Comment: The abbreviated form of pounds and ounces are “lb” and “oz”. However, 6'9'' does mean 6 feet and 9 inches. For instance, think about TV and PC monitors for instance (24'' = 24 inches across). 6' is the size a fairly tall human.

Comment: And an even taller cat. Thanks,Morgan. Of course,??could also mean part of his latitude and longitude

Comment: Or a really tall cat who lives at 6'9" longitude or latitude,I suppose...Thanks,Morgan.

Comment: It depends which system you are using ([DMS: Degree Minutes Seconds or DD: Decimal Degrees](http://www.latlong.net/degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-degrees)). Since the notation for minutes and seconds is also 5'30" (for a stop watch for example) for 5 mins 30 seconds, using the DMS will also use ' and " in its notation. "Lat" and "Long" are the abbreviations for latitude and longitude, but the DMS system adds mins and secs in both Lat and Long.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/114205/64632

Comment: I am thankful I live in a country and era that (mostly) uses grams and kg instead of that nonsensical imperial system 

Answer (score 4):

' and " can mean a few things, including feet and inches or minutes and seconds (in the senses of either time or angle). However pounds and ounces is not one.

The appropriate abbreviation for pounds is **lb**, and for ounces is **oz**.